# DNA pairing problem. How to ensure we ignore invalid Characters

Tags: javascript

I am writing code to take a string and return an array containing matched DNA pairs. The problem I am running into is that the code solution I have come up with is not ignoring invalid characters in the string.

For example...

```
'GTTC' => ['GC', 'TA', 'TA', 'CG']
```

Using my solution the above test works fine...however...I would like the below solution to work also - and ignore the invalid characters to have the below output

```
 'PGYYYHVB' => ['GC']
```

I have completed a solution below but as mentioned need to look into what will help me ignore the invalid characters

```
function pairDNA(dna) {
  let str = dna.split("");
  let arr = [];
  const pairs = { A: 'AT', T: 'TA', G: 'GC', C: 'CG' }
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    arr.push(pairs[str[i].toUpperCase()])
}
return arr
```

This is the current output on the tests with invalid characters...

```
  AssertionError: expected [ Array(8) ] to deeply equal [ 'GC' ]
  + expected - actual

   [
  -  [undefined]
     "GC"
  -  [undefined]
  -  [undefined]
  -  [undefined]
  -  [undefined]
  -  [undefined]
  -  [undefined]
   ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a check, if the character exist.

```
var character;

// ...
for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    character = str[i].toUpperCase();
    if (character in pairs) arr.push(pairs[character]);
}
```

Comment: You might need to perform a `hasOwnProperty` check with `in` to ensure you don't crawl the parent proto

Answer (score 0):

Before splitting the DNA string, try running:
`dna.replace(/[bdefhijklmnopqrsuvwxyz]/ig, "");`

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in the `for` loop.

If there is an invalid character that is not found as a property of the object, it will return `undefined`. However, you will need to `continue` the iteration if there is no value.

Change the `for` loop to be:

```
for (let i = 0; i < dna.length; ++i) {
    if (pairs[dna[i].toUpperCase()]) {
        output.push(pairs[dna[i].toUpperCase()]);
    }
}
```

The `if` statement will only execute if there is a match.

Hope it helps :)